# Ckeditor editor.pasteFilter.allow and editor.pasteFilter.disallow not working on window

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

```
   CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(ck) {
        ck.editor.pasteFilter.allow('div span');
        ck.editor.pasteFilter.disallow('a[name]');
   });
```

Trying to disallow "a" tag with "name" attribute on paste and allow "div" and "span".

Working on Linux, Mac in both chrome and Firefox

But not working on Window any browser

Using paster-filter in config

```
  pasteFilter: 'semantic-content'
  disallowedContent: 'script; *[on*]'
```

Comment: I tested it on Virtual Windows and seems to work fine for me. I used this code for testing: https://codepen.io/msamsel/pen/bYvyGY?editors=1010
Maybe you tried to copy non-external data? There is an info in documentation that pasteFilter is not applied to such data source: https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-pasteFilter
"Note that the paste filter is applied only to **external** data."